# How to how to create a Dataframe based on a condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new DataFrame from another for rows that meet a condition such as:

```
uk_cities_df['location'] = cities_df['El Tarter'].where(cities_df['AD'] == 'GB')
uk_cities_df[:5]
```

but the resulting uk_cities_df is returning NaN.

The csv file that I am needing to extract from has no headers so it used the first row values for such. I need to only include rows in `uk_cities_df` include the ISO code "GB" so "El Tarter" denotes the values for location and "AD" for iso code.

Comment: Can you share sample DataFrame for `cities_df` and `uk_cities_df`

Comment: how does your df look like? pandas where returns NaN as default if condition  `cities_df['AD'] == 'GB'` is False.

Comment: That's my bad, I want to only include the rows that meet that condition. So I assume I need to use loc instead

Comment: The df uk_cities_df is empty, i want to fill it with the locations in cities_df that have the iso code "GB". The column for location is "El Tartar" as there is no proper headings assicoated and the ISO header is "AD"

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide a visual of what uk_cities_df and cities_df look like ?

From what I can gather, I think you might be looking for the .loc operator,
you could try for example :

```
uk_cities_df['location'] = cities_df.loc[cities_df['AD'] == 'GB']['location']
```

Also, I did not really get what role 'El Tarter' plays here, maybe you could give more details ?